# Relative and absolute error $\sin(x)$

Tags: numerical-methods, standard-error

> Estimate the absolute error in determining $\sin(x)$. 
> Estimate the relative error in determining $\sin(x)$.

I know how to calculate these for a specific $x$ with the formula
\begin{align}
\textrm{Absolute Error = Calculated value - True value}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\textrm{Relative Error = Absolute Error / True value}.
\end{align} But there is no specific $x$, could someone help me where to begin? It's probably because I don't understand the question?

Comment: You are quoting your problems out of context which makes it hard to help you. My best guess is that you have just been taught about absolute and relative condition numbers and that you now expected to apply these definitions and associated formula.

Comment: So do you think I should choose multiple $x$ by myself?

Comment: No, you should edit your question and provide additional context as the appropriate answer will depend on the context. Your question is in danger of  being closed unless you do this.